# Как найти нужный текст на HTML странице?

Tags: javascript, html

Допустим нужно совершить проверку на фразу "Я нуб в JavaScript", как это сделать?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 6):

Ну, допустим, так:

```js
function find() {
    if (document.body.innerHTML.match("Я нуб в JavaScript") != null)
        alert("Found!");
    else
        alert("Not found!");
}
```

```html
<p>Я нуб в JavaScript</p>
<button onclick="find();">Click me!</button>
```